# Rails 5 and Mysql2 gem issue

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, mysql2

I am trying to upgrade a `Rails 4` app to `Rails 5`, looks like all went well and also `bundle install` succeeds. however when I try to start up the server I see two errors in the below sequence

```
1. Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'mysql2'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord). (Gem::LoadError)
2. can't activate mysql2 (>= 0.3.18, < 0.5), already activated mysql2-0.5.5. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
```

Version details are

```
1. Ruby: 2.6.10
2. Rails 5.1
3. bundler 1.17.3
```

below is the logs of the exception

```
/Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:188:in `rescue in spec': Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'mysql2'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord). (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:185:in `spec'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:880:in `establish_connection'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:58:in `establish_connection'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:124:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `execute_hook'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:35:in `block in on_load'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `each'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `on_load'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:120:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/dev_user/Desktop/Development/Rails/syzygy/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
    from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:24:in `app'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:80:in `log_to_stdout'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:42:in `start'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `block in perform'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:125:in `tap'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:125:in `perform'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
/Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:408:in `block (2 levels) in replace_gem': can't activate mysql2 (>= 0.3.18, < 0.5), already activated mysql2-0.5.5. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:186:in `spec'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:880:in `establish_connection'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:58:in `establish_connection'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:124:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `execute_hook'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:35:in `block in on_load'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `each'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `on_load'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:120:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/dev_user/Desktop/Development/Rails/syzygy/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
    from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:24:in `app'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:80:in `log_to_stdout'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:42:in `start'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `block in perform'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:125:in `tap'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:125:in `perform'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
    from /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

any help on how I could fix this would be great, Thanks

Comment: How did you try to start the Rails server? Just with `rails s` or with `bundle exec rails s`? Did you add `gem 'mysql2'` to your `Gemfile`? `What version of `mysql2` did `bundle install` install?

Comment: Hi, I tried to run the sever both using `rails s` and `bundle exec rails s` but see the same error. mysql2 version installed is `0.5.5`

Comment: ah I now see this ```cat /Users/dev_user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb
require "active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter"
require "active_record/connection_adapters/mysql/database_statements"

gem "mysql2", ">= 0.3.18", "< 0.5"
require "mysql2"
raise "mysql2 0.4.3 is not supported. Please upgrade to 0.4.4+" if Mysql2::VERSION == "0.4.3"
``` looks like rails 5.1 needs mysql2 < 0.5?