# active_record 5.1 pointing to earlier version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have upgraded a rails application to Rails 5.1 and see a strange issue.

When I check the `mysql2_adapter.rb` for the active_record gem I that the top 3 Line are

```
require "active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter"
require "active_record/connection_adapters/mysql/database_statements"

gem "mysql2", ">= 0.3.18", "< 0.5"
```

however when I check the active_record gem on GitHub for the version 5.1 I see that the lines are different

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-1-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb

```
require "active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter"
require "active_record/connection_adapters/mysql/database_statements"

gem "mysql2", ">= 0.3.18", "< 0.6.0"
```

Can anyone please help as to why the active_record 5.1 on my local machine has different code compared to what's on GitHub.

may be I missed something during rails upgrade.

Comment: What does `gem active_record -v` return?

Comment: Can you force the upgrade with `gem update active_record`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version you see on Github was the outcome of this [pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/32310) being merged on 2018-03-18. After that date, only [Ruby on Rails 5.1.6 and 5.1.7 were released](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions?page=2).

But when I look at the [stack trace of your question from yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76189261/rails-5-and-mysql2-gem-issue), it feels like you are running Ruby on Rails `5.1.0`.

That means your Ruby on Rails version is about one year older than the latest Ruby on Rails 5.1.x version on GitHub.

I suggest updating your Rails version at least to `5.1.7` by adding

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.7'
```

to your `Gemfile` and then running `bundle install` again.